# Serving CSS in PHP file (using IIS)

Tags: php, css, iis

I'm trying output CSS using PHP to can make it more dynamic with wordpress settings but I'm getting 500 internal server error.
I'm setting the header to text/css, tried to add handlers in IIS but it doesn't seem to work. Have no errors in the PHP file because if I remove my code it doesn't change.

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

Whereas adding following to .htaccess works in case of apache server

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .css
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .css
```

This is the response i get using IIS:

```
   HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

   Content-Type: text/css

   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0

   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13

   Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2012 16:38:12 GMT

   Content-Length: 0
```

Any idea how to get this working under IIS?

Comment: Are you sure that there's no error in your PHP file? I think that that would also give you a 500 error....

Comment: `tried to add handlers in IIS ` - Does this include mime types when you select the mime types option?

Comment: No mimi-type option when adding a handler? Elaborate please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to an IIS 7 configuration problem

Ensure that `Static Content` is enabled in Common HTTP Features when configuring IIS from the Windows Add and Remove programs - [IIS 7 Not Serving Static Files](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/IIS-7-Not-Serving-Static-Files.aspx). Another reference - [Funny Problem: Windows 7, IIS 7.5: Images, CSS not showing!](http://gurustop.net/blog/2009/10/12/funny-problem-windows-7-iis-7-5-images-css-not-showing/)

Alternatively try [Wildcard script mapping and IIS 7 integrated pipeline](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-integrated-pipeline) or just simply re-install IIS.